# Differentiation with respect to radial direction

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

This is a question that I've had since my PDE classes. Let us be in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is fixed. Define $$\phi(r) = \int_{\partial B(0,1)} u(x+ry) d \sigma(y) ,$$
where $u: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, $d\sigma$ is the surface measure. $r$ is supposed to represent a "radial distance", and I'm not entirely sure what it is. Furthermore, there is this calculation $$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}  = \int_{\partial B(0,1)} (\nabla u(x+ry) \cdot y) \, d \sigma(y),$$ that I don't know how to justify. Can anyone help with this? Thanks.

Comment: This is differentiation under the integral sign and the chain rule. You're studying (a constant times) the average value of $u$ on the sphere of radius $r$ centered at $x$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry, but could you be a bit more explicit? If I use the chain rule, then $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} = \sum_i \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial r}  $. How does this imply the result? I get that we take the partial derivative with respect to $r$ inside the integral. I'm also not entirely sure what $ \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial r}$ looks like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**: Write $u=u(z)$, where $z=x+ry$; here $x$ is fixed and $y$ varies over the unit sphere. We take the $r$ derivative under the integral sign, obtaining
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial r} u(x+ry) = \nabla u(x+ry)\cdot \frac{\partial(x+ry)}{\partial r} = \nabla u(x+ry)\cdot y.$$
If you insist on writing it out in the confusing coordinate notation, write
$$\sum\frac{\partial u}{\partial z_i}(x+ry)\frac{\partial z_i}{\partial r} = \sum\frac{\partial u}{\partial z_i}(x+ry)\, y_i,$$
as you were trying to do.

Comment: Well in my notation it would be $\sum\frac{\partial u}{\partial (x+ry)_i}\frac{\partial (x+ry)_i}{\partial r} = \sum u_{x_i} y_i$ where $(x+ry)_i = x_i + ry_i$ but point taken  : ) thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Hi Ted. I know this question is quite old, but may I ask why we can differentiate under the integral sign in this case?

Comment: @Bill We certainly are assuming $u$ is $C^1$ or better.